# What is the best Minecraft base defense to use against online players

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

These guys keep raiding my base and it usually ends up in total destruction due to TNT. They won't fall for traps and usually they TNT anything they see as a path to my base. How can I outsmart them?

Answer (score 3):

## Blast proofing is a thing. Or hide pressure plates in with the surroundings.

A smart play is to waterlog your outside walls by placing stairs facing toward your base around your base (so they won't know the stairs are waterlogged >:D) with obsidian behind it, and replace the floors and walls with waterlogged slabs/stairs.

Oh and your bridge could be made of all waterlogged slabs (1x1 would be extra annoying) too (moats!), with Magma Blocks at the bottom so if they fall in, they're not making it out alive and obsidian walls around it so they can't mine their way out.

And for the finale, replace the blocks outside the obsidian walls with waterlogged slabs, except for specific ones that have pressure plates on top with TNT underneath (The waterlogged slabs are there so they don't get blown up by the TNT), making the far outside a minefield, outside an evil blast proof moat, and inside blast proof (Ender Chests have Obsidian Blast resistance, and so do Enchantment tables).

Comment: Also make sure the moat is filled with full water source blocks, which can be done easily by placing sand (Soul Sand also works) at the bottom at first and then placing kelp on top of that to the surface (this makes the water full source blocks), otherwise the bubble suction columns won't spawn.

Comment: Thank you so much they won't know what coming!

Comment: No problem! The Magma Block moat can just make them die quickly, and the Waterlogged Blocks should make them really confused when they try to blow them up, plus the hidden pressure Mine Field is just plain evil (to them) because then they will just step on the pressure plates trying to speed through (trying to avoid the pressure plates, of course).

Answer (score 2):

### The safest base is always a hidden base.

My suggestion to you would be to rebuild a couple thousand blocks away, preferably underground with no visible access point (i.e. just note the coordinates and cover the entrance). Any other defenses can be bypassed in some way. A list of techniques that may be used against you.

- Going to the nether to bypass walls.
- Ender-pearling through walls.
- Elytra above the build limit.
- Just plain mining.
- Use chorus fruit to teleport through walls, though this is mainly luck-based.

(Please comment with more methods; I know I am missing several.)

### If a hidden base is not an option.

If you are trying to protect a base that you assume people will find, here are a couple tactics that may help in base defense.

- Add a water layer to your walls. This makes mining difficult, and largely negates the effect of TNT.
- Add a layer of sand-gravel with lava at the top, preferably followed by an obsidian layer. This makes your wall annoying to mine through. As a bonus, if your would-be raider isn't paying attention while mining, they get lava in the face.

Comment: I used to play faction servers alot and people still found it somehow. I mean it's a good solution but it's not foolproof either lol

Comment: If you want to hide your base with style, this video has a lot of cool hidden entrances.  =) https://youtu.be/O6b5GeYEJm4

Comment: Chorus fruit can also be used to bypass walls, they just have to get lucky.

Comment: I already covered the water layer, though the Lava/sand-gravel + obsidian would be even eviler if added my answer stated above. So a combination of these tactics would result in a completely grief/raid-proof base >=D